# Resgatar resultados no r

Tags: r, funções

É possível resgatar apenas o p-value de uma regressão linear simples no R?

eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
reg<-lm(abscissa~ordenada)

summary(reg)
```

a resposta é:

```
Call:
lm(formula = abscissa ~ ordenada)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-746.77 -308.91  -62.22  285.36 1236.04 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 2163.1769   161.4879  13.395  < 2e-16 ***

ordenada       1.7729     0.2735   6.482 8.95e-09 ***

Signif. codes:  0 *** 0.001 ** 0.01 * 0.05 . 0.1 '' 1

Residual standard error: 452.9 on 74 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.3621,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.3535 
F-statistic: 42.01 on 1 and 74 DF,  p-value: 8.951e-09
```

eu preciso chamar apenas o p-value (8.951e-09)

tentei usar o operados $ mas sem sucesso.

Grato

Comment: É o p-valor da estatística F ou da estatística T?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apesar dos cálculos da [resposta do Tomás Barcellos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/359332/resgatar-resultados-no-r/359343#359343) estarem certos, o objeto `sumario` já tem os p-valores:

```
reg <- lm(mpg ~ wt, mtcars)
sumario <- summary(reg)

sumario$coefficients[, 4]
# (Intercept)           wt 
#8.241799e-19 1.293959e-10
```

Para ter só o segundo p-valor, corra o comando acima mas desta vez com o índice de linha.

```
sumario$coefficients[2, 4]
#[1] 1.293959e-10
```

Veja o que `sumario$coefficients` tem. Para ver o objeto `sumario` completo a melhor opção é correr `str(sumario)` e depois perder algum tempo a ler a saída deste comando. (Nunca me lembro exatamente onde estão os p-valores.)

Comment: Boa. A forma como fiz é como o `print.summary.lm()` faz.

Comment: Veja o que acontece quando há mais de uma variável explicativa, por exemplo, `reg <- lm(mpg ~ wt + disp, mtcars)`. O seu método fica diferente do resultado de `print`. Nem `0.06` nem `0.007` são iguais ao p-valor que está na nona casa decimal.

Comment: O resultado que me dá com `options(digits = 15)` é `c('(Intercept)' = 4.91074607571808e-16, wt = 0.00743072516192677, 
disp = 0.0636198070339208)`. E com o valor por defeito é `4.910746e-16 7.430725e-03 6.361981e-02 ` mas o `dput` dá a mesma coisa tal e qual.

Comment: Estamos falando de p-valor diferentes. Tem um p-valor que é único para cada modelo e outro para cada variável do modelo. A minha resposta dá o primeiro, a sua dá o segundo. No caso de regressões simples esses valores são iguais. O p-valor que estou falando é a última coisa impressa do sumário

Comment: @TomásBarcellos Certo, não tinha percebido. Creio então que a pergunta é ambígua, devia pedir claramente o que quer. Eu interpretei como sendo os p-valores das estatísticas `t` e é isso que a minha resposta dá.

Answer (score 3):

O p-valor não existe no objeto de sumário. O que o objeto de sumário oferece são as condições de calcular o p-valor, com a estatística F e os dois graus de liberdade.

```
reg <- lm(mpg ~ wt, mtcars)
sumario <- summary(reg)
estatisticas <- sumario$fstatistic
estatisticas
#    value    numdf    dendf 
# 91.37533  1.00000 30.00000
```

Com essas informações em mãos podemos calcular o p-valor usado o pacote `stats`, que já começa carregado em um sessão padrão do `R`.

```
pvalor <- stats::pf(estatisticas[1], estatisticas[2], estatisticas[3], lower.tail = FALSE)
#        value 
# 1.293959e-10
```

Se quiser que o p-valor esteja formatado bonitinho, como quando ocorre a impressão do sumário, você pode

```
format.pval(pvalor, 3)
# [1] "1.29e-10"
```

Comment: Perfeito Tomás, obrigada pela contribuição. De fato a outra metodologia resulta em erro para modelos com múltiplas variáveis.